# how to customise the bg-color of the menu in elementUI

Tags: vue.js

In elementUI the default background-color is white ; when choosing the them:dark , it is black, but how can I customise the bg-color by myself?
I have tried to add the style property at the el-menu tag , but it didn't work

```
<el-menu style="{background-color: rgb(36,36,36)!important}"
```

I try to find the source code of the css file of el-menu tag and I try to change some setting relating to background-color, don't work either

the menu component just like 
[image]

somebody told me I can code like this
`<el-menu style="{backgroundColor: yello}.."` but it didn't work

Comment: Override css in your component `.el-menu-item.is-active {
    background-color: #20a0ff;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `class` for that particular element is not modifiable, have a look:

```
:class="{
    'el-menu--horizontal': mode === 'horizontal',
    'el-menu--dark': theme === 'dark',
    'el-menu--collapse': collapse
  }"
```

So your choices are:

1. Wrap it in a custom `<div class="my-specific-selector` and target it with `.my-specific-selector .el-menu`
2. Override the CSS for the dark theme
3. Copy + paste contents of component into your own file, adjust accordingly, use that instead.

Comment: is it neccessary to create a custom tag `<div class="my-specific-selector` and use it to target with the `el-menu`? can I directly target the el-menu and override the style of it

Comment: @LucasFang Sure, but I don't know your use case.

Answer (score 0):

you can try put background color directly like this

```
<el-menu
  background-color="#304156"
  text-color="#bfcbd9"
  active-text-color="#409EFF"
  style="height: 61px;"
></el-menu>
```